# If I have a custom method in my Model class, how do I have it executed when a link is pressed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a method called `set_score`, on my `Client` model.

On my `Clients#index` view, I would like to create a button/link that says 'Update Score' and all this does is sends the requisite params to that method and runs it.

How do I do that?

Can I do that with a Rails link helper?

**Edit 1:**

For what it's worth, right now that method is executed by a `callback` (i.e. `before_save`). But I want to give the user the ability to trigger it manually.

Comment: You hook up a route to a controller method that calls the model method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @meagar pointed out, the way to do this is to create a custom action in my controller, then create a route and then use that named route in a `link_to` in my view.

My `Client#Controller` now has this method:

```
def update_score
    @client = current_user.clients.find(params[:id])
    @client.set_score

respond_to do |format|
  if @client.update_attributes(params[:client])
    format.html { redirect_to clients_url, notice: 'Score was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

My `routes.rb` now has this route:

```
match ':controller/update_score/:id' => 'clients#update_score', :as => :update_score
```

And in my view, I just used this link, where `client` is a local variable generated by the block.

```
<%= link_to 'Update Score', update_score_path(client) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an action to a controller which invokes the method on the model, and then add a route to allow a request to reach that action. Make your link invoke that route.

The browser can't talk to models directly. That's what controllers are for.

Comment: Surely you have at least one controller, and at least one model, and at least one route. This is literally the simplest possible Rails application. Find and follow *any* tutorial and you should have your answer.